# Tilemill didn't render streets correctly, some parts are missing

Tags: tilemill, osm2pgsql, rendering, cartocss

can someone please explain me what's happend in the picture below or how i can debug what's going wrong? I downloaded some .osm.pbf files imported the files via osm2pgsql into a postgis database and render the tiles using tilemill with the openstreetmap-carto project. Some parts of the Streets are missing.

[image: Coruppted Streets]

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the way types are the same? Might not be translating from cartoCSS/mapnik to postgis... If you need to patch data together should try overpass api to query for and join the missing data

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a recent version of osm2pgsql?

Older versions (prior to 2013) can not handle node numbers correctly since these have hit the 32-bit limit.

The Windows version still might have issues, see https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/17 for the latest development builds.

Answer (score 0):

I used a version of osm2pgsql that can handle 64-bit IDs. I think it happens when I merged some pbf data files with osm2pgsql into one database or "style" the data with the style attribute that osm2pgsql offers.
I rebuild the Database using osmconvert to put thinks together and osm2pgsql to import that merged file into the postGIS Databse (without style=). Now the exported tiles looks file.

Thanks for your answers. They pointed me in the right direction!