# TileMill Missing Streets HERE street data

Tags: tilemill, rendering

I am creating tiles with TileMill. Before adding layers to TileMill I'm checking the geometries for errors and I'm not seeing any
[image]

However, once I add the street layer to TileMill there are missing streets[image]

I thought maybe this was isolated to a rendering issue in TileMill and would disappear after I generated tiles, but the problem persisted afterwards when I loaded it into GeoServer.

This is the styling I'm using in TileMill

```
#MtViewStreets3CLs[zoom>12]{
line-width:1;
line-color:#b6b6b6;
}

#MtViewStreets3CLs[zoom>14]{
  line-width:1;
  line-color:#b6b6b6;
  text-name:[ST_NAME];
  text-face-name:"Arial Regular";
  text-fill:#838383;
  text-size: 11;
  text-placement: line;
  text-min-path-length:100;
  text-avoid-edges:true;
  text-min-distance:50;
  text-dy: 6;
  text-max-char-angle-delta: 15;
}
```

I checked this post but it's not the same issue I'm having:

[Tilemill didn't render streets correctly, some parts are missing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119700/tilemill-didnt-render-streets-correctly-some-parts-are-missing)